# Declare a php constant within a php variable

Tags: php, string, variables, echo, constants

I have the following code:

```
<?php $background_holder = echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');'/images/banner.jpg';?>
background-image: url("<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_background_image', $background_holder;); ?>");
```

I'm trying to set a constant for the `$background_holder` and then add it to the background image variable. I'm sure I've just written something slightly wrong, but currently this does nothing.

Comment: Try this `<?php $background_holder = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/banner.jpg';?>`

Comment: remove echo, <?php $background_holder =  get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/banner.jpg';?>

Comment: Sam, you are trying to echo a string into a variable... `echo` is not needed in the 1st line, since it outputs the contents into the page. So you can first build your string and save it to the variable: `$background_holder = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/banner.jpg'` (notice that you need `.` instead of `;` for concatenating the string). And then in the 2nd line you just need to remove the `;` before the `)` for not having a syntax error, like this: `get_theme_mod('header_background_image', $background_holder);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$background_holder` is just a variable you're assigning a variable to, no need to `echo`. Additionally, seems like you're trying to concat `'/images/banner.jpg' to some base directory. If this is the case, you'd need to use the concatination operator (`.`):

```
<?php $background_holder = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/banner.jpg';?>
background-image: url("<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_background_image', $background_holder); ?>");
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked great - and I learnt something new - cheers